# Simple Jasmine example for a change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine and was looking for an example to test a very simple `change` event handler.

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myId").change(function() {
         my.functionOne();
    });
});

my = {
    functionOne : function() {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

How do I test that when my event handler is executed, functionOne is called?

Thanks.

Comment: Not the answer you were hoping for, but don't declare empty wrapper functions instead of: `$("#myId").change(function() {
         my.functionOne();});` use: `$("#myId").change(my.functionOne);`

Comment: Old response - but there is a reason for the first over the second - the first means that "this" will be "my" in the first line. The "this" in the second line will be something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Jasmine documentation on Spies: http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Spies

The simplest way to test the event handler would be something like this:

```
describe('#myId behaviour', function(){
    //.. Your other setup here.

    it('calls functionOne on #myId change event', function(){
        spyOn(my, 'functionOne');

        // Force a change event to fire.
        $("#myId").trigger('change');

        expect(my.functionOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    // Other tests...
}
```

---

I don't know how you've got your tests set up with HTML and jQuery but these two libraries might come in handy as well:

- Set up jQuery and HTML fixtures before each test: https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture
- Test the state: https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery

Comment: is this still how you would do it in Jasmine 2? not working for me, and i've tried both using the `affix` and `loadFixtures` set ups...

Comment: @james yes, that is still how I would do it with Jasmine 2. Post a question with your specific setup and then @ me in the comments and I can have a look.

Comment: thanks, just did that, also, link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549942/jasmine-trigger-event-not-working