# Jasmine - trigger event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Code that I'm trying to test:

```
$(".toggle_item").on("change", function() {
  console.log("change triggered")
  item_name = $(this).data("name");
  value = $(this).prop("checked");
  if (Item.isValid(item_name) && cartModule.isUnique(item_name)) { 
    cartModule.toggleItem(item_name, value); 
  }
})
```

Jasmine spec:

```
describe("changing toggle item", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    console.log("in spec")
    affix(".toggle_item[data-name='ladder']")
    spyOn(cartModule, "isUnique") 
    spyOn(Item, "isValid")
    $(".toggle_item").trigger("change")
  })

  it("should check item for validity & cart for uniqueness", function() {
    expect(Item.isValid).toHaveBeenCalledWith("ladder")
    expect(cartModule.isUnique).toHaveBeenCalledWith("ladder")
  })
})
```

The console log output indicates that the trigger did not fire. Log output:

```
> "in spec"
```

FWIW:

- I have tried using both `affix` and `loadFixtures`
- I have tried using both `$(".toggle_item").on("change"...` and `$(".toggle_item").change...`

Gem list:

```
jasmine (2.7.0)
jasmine-core (2.8.0, 2.7.0)
jasmine-jquery-rails (2.0.3)
jasmine-rails (0.14.1)
```

Comment: @sly_cardinal this is the situation I was asking you about on the other comment section, the `trigger("change")` isn't forcing the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Updated answer: 2018-02-03**

The fundamental issue here is that your code is **running** too early, before your fixtures have been set up. This is different to loading your code before all of your tests. You need to be able to control when your code **runs** after it has been **loaded**.

This is more to do with how you write your code so that it can be tested, and is largely independent of the tools and libraries that are actually being used for testing.

Here is an example:

```
// There is no way to test this expression - it runs as soon as it is loaded
1 + 2


// This is similar to the line above - it tries to add the event listener as soon
// as the line of code is encountered. If you haven't set up fixtures before this line is run
// then you can't test it.
$('.toggle_item').on('change', ...);


// Here is an example of code that is testable
// It is testable because we have separated out the loading of the code 
// from the **invocation** of the code.
function add(){
    // i.e. This expression will only run when `add()` is invoked.
    return 1 + 2;
}


// Here is an example that adds a bit more control over when the event listeners are added.
$(function(){
    // This expression runs when `$.ready` is fired (aka `DOMContentLoaded`)
    // If you can delay `$.ready` until your fixtures are set up then this will work.
    $('.toggle_item').on('change', ...);
})
```

---

The explanation in [your linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191966/jquery-triggerclick-not-working-with-jasmine-jquery) isn't quite right. `$('.selector').click(...)` is just an alias or short-hand for `$('.selector').on('click', ...)` so changing to that won't make any difference - they are functionally exactly the same.

The reason that answer actually works in that case is because the event listener is being added in the `$.ready()` event instead of immediately as soon as the code is loaded.

It's the difference between running this:

```
console.log('1 before');
console.log('2 middle');
console.log('3 after');
```

Result:

```
> 1 before
> 2 middle
> 3 after
```

And running this:

```
console.log('1 before');
$(function(){
    console.log('2 middle');
});
console.log('3 after');
```

Result:

```
> 1 before
> 3 after
> 2 middle
```

---

Another tool that might help you here is [delegated event listeners](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Bascially, you add a single event listener to an element further up the DOM tree which listens for events from particular child selectors.

e.g.:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.toggle_item', function(){

    });
})
```

The benefit of this is that the event listener can be added early, event before `.toggle_item` exists, but the listeners will be fired once the elements have been added.

There are some caveats to using event delegates (e.g. when using `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()`) but they are still a very useful tool.

---

**Original answer**

In your code under test are you able to control/delay when the event listener is added?

I suspect that your code is trying to add the event listener to `.toggle_item` before the `affix(".toggle_item[data-name='ladder']")` statement is being run in your tests.

```
console.log('Adding listener')
$(".toggle_item").on("change", function() {
    console.log("change triggered")
    ...
});
```

You'll know it's out of order if you get:

```
> "Adding listener"
> "in spec"
```

Instead of what we want:

```
> "in spec"
> "Adding listener"
```

Comment: you're right! is this an easy/common fix? I didn't see it in the docs for loading fixtures...

Comment: The fix depends on your application code - you need to be able to prevent your code from adding event listeners until your fixtures are in place. If you only add the event listeners in jQuery's `ready` event then you might be able to use [$.holdReady(...)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/) to delay the ready event until you have set up your fixtures. Otherwise, you need to find some other way of deferring your application initialisation until your tests are ready.

Comment: I understand what you're saying in theory. If you will, a more general question, because I just started Jasmine. Is this not the way people write tests for code for user actions? I can't find in docs for any fixtures anywhere how to delay adding event listeners. Moreover, it's part of regular Jasmine behavior to initialize the JS code, and then all of test code. So... how does this normally get tested because it seems like it doesn't...

Comment: Also, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191966/jquery-triggerclick-not-working-with-jasmine-jquery, suggests using `on("change")` so that all future added DOM elements are bound as well. Incidentally, that raises a good point. I do have `on("change")` so that should have worked right?

Comment: @james I've added some extra info about change events and order of execution

Comment: ok this makes sense, I'm loathe to use `$(document).ready` since as the script gets more complex, I don't think it makes sense to use something that's not very efficient (i.e., having the document examine all events that bubble). The `$(function(){` + `holdReady` combo looks more interesting. I've been doing some Googling... do you know how to actually holdReady until the fixtures load? I'm not sure how to implement this...